# How to count the total array elements [[]] using javascript

Tags: javascript, count

My array with element,

```
var count =[["test1.img","test2.img","test3.img"]];
```

If I count array element [] single dimensional, The count is working fine But If I use like this [[]], It's not working.

**MY Question**

How to count the total array elements in a two-dimensional array.

The output should be 3.

Thanks

Comment: `count[0].length` or you want something more?show complex question and more expected output?

Comment: please add the (not) working code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an error with this 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656681/why-am-i-getting-an-error-with-this-2d-array)

Comment: @xianshenglu your answer is working fine for me thnx

Comment: @NinaScholz  I want to count the total array elements in given line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the count of the inner array.

1. The number of elements in an array the simple way is to use
   Array.length.
2. In your case, you would use `count[0].length`.

```js
    var count =[["test1.img","test2.img","test3.img"]];
    var result = count[0].length;
    console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a array of arrays and you want to sum up the length of all the array items. You can try following using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
// Code goes here

var arr = [["test1.img","test2.img","test3.img"]];

var count = arr.reduce(function(a, subArray){
  return a + subArray.length;
}, 0);

console.log(count);
```